# FFmpeg script on all files in folder

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I've seen lots of answers for this.

I'm trying to convert all videos in a folder to audio with.

```
for i in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -vn -acodec copy "${i%.*}.aac"; done
```

FFmpeg throws the error:

```
*.mp4: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone let me know how to do this?

Comment: Are there actually any `.mp4` files in (the top level of) the current directory? or are they all inside subdirectories? Does `ls *.mp4` return anything?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @steeldriver for [the comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1160838/ffmpeg-script-on-all-files-in-folder/1161103#comment1933495_1160838) suggesting there might not be any files with that name in the current directory and they might be in subdirectories instead.

It was dumber than that... the files were all .MP4 (note the case).